# Adding two javascript visuals to html page

Tags: javascript, html, css, d3.js, display

I'm trying to add two d3 visuals to my index.html page, but only one of the visuals displays at a time. The two visuals use the same code and the only difference is the data used. They work well individually, but I am unable to get them to appear on the same page together.

```js
var margins = {
    top: 20,
    bottom: 300,
    left: 30,
    right: 100
};

var height = 800;
var width = 500;

var totalWidth = width + margins.left + margins.right;
var totalHeight = height + margins.top + margins.bottom;

var svg = d3.select('body')
    .append('svg')
    .attr('width', totalWidth)
    .attr('height', totalHeight);

var graphGroup = svg.append('g')
    .attr('transform', "translate(" + margins.left + "," + margins.top + ")");

var levels = [
    [
        {id: 'Gaia'},
        {id:'Ouranos', parents:['Gaia']}

    ],

    [
        {id:'Aphrodite', parents:['Ouranos']},
        {id: 'Themis', parents: ['Gaia', 'Ouranos']},
        {id: 'Mnemosyne', parents: ['Gaia', 'Ouranos']},
        {id: 'Hyperion', parents: ['Gaia', 'Ouranos']},
        {id: 'Thea', parents: ['Gaia', 'Ouranos']},
        {id: 'Crius', parents: ['Gaia', 'Ouranos']},

        {id: 'Oceanus', parents: ['Gaia', 'Ouranos']},
        {id: 'Tethys', parents: ['Gaia', 'Ouranos']},
        {id: 'Iapetus', parents: ['Gaia', 'Ouranos']},

        {id: 'Coeus', parents: ['Gaia', 'Ouranos']},
        {id: 'Phoebe', parents: ['Gaia','Ouranos']},
        {id: 'Kronos', parents: ['Gaia', 'Ouranos']},
        {id: 'Rhea', parents: ['Gaia', 'Ouranos']},

    ],
    [
        {id: 'Pleione', parents:['Oceanus','Tethys']},
        {id:'Atlas',parents:['Iapetus']},
        {id:'Semele'},
        {id:'Maia', parents:['Pleione','Atlas']},
        {id:'Leto',parents:['Coeus','Phoebe']},
        {id:'Zeus',parents:['Kronos','Rhea']},
        {id:'Hera',parents:['Kronos','Rhea']},
        {id:'Poseidon',parents:['Kronos','Rhea']},
        {id:'Amphitrite'},
        {id:'Hestia',parents:['Kronos','Rhea']},
        {id:'Hades',parents:['Kronos','Rhea']},
        {id:'Demeter',parents:['Kronos','Rhea']},


    ],


    [
        {id:'Dionysus',parents:['Semele','Zeus']},
        {id:'Hermes',parents:['Maia','Zeus']},
        {id:'Apollo',parents:['Leto','Zeus']},
        {id:'Artemis',parents:['Leto','Zeus']},
        {id:'Athena',parents:['Zeus']},
        {id:'Ares',parents:['Zeus','Hera']},
        {id:'Hephaistos',parents:['Zeus','Hera']},
        {id:'Hebe',parents:['Zeus','Hera']},
        {id:'Triton',parents:['Poseidon','Amphitrite']},
        {id:'Benthesikyme',parents:['Poseidon','Amphitrite']},
        {id:'Rhodos',parents:['Poseidon','Amphitrite']},
        {id:'Persephone',parents:['Zeus','Demeter']},

        {id:'Zagreus', parents:['Hades','Persephone']},
        {id:'Macaria', parents:['Hades','Persephone']}
    ]

]

// precompute level depth
levels.forEach((l, i) => l.forEach(n => n.level = i));

var nodes = levels.reduce(((a, x) => a.concat(x)), []);
var nodes_index = {};
nodes.forEach(d => nodes_index[d.id] = d);

// objectification
nodes.forEach(d => {
    d.parents = (d.parents === undefined ? [] : d.parents).map(p => nodes_index[p])
})

// precompute bundles
levels.forEach((l, i) => {
    var index = {}
    l.forEach(n => {
        if (n.parents.length == 0) {
            return
        }

        var id = n.parents.map(d => d.id).sort().join('--')
        if (id in index) {
            index[id].parents = index[id].parents.concat(n.parents)
        } else {
            index[id] = {
                id: id,
                parents: n.parents.slice(),
                level: i
            }
        }
        n.bundle = index[id]
    })
    l.bundles = Object.keys(index).map(k => index[k])
    l.bundles.forEach((b, i) => b.i = i)
})

var links = []
nodes.forEach(d => {
    d.parents.forEach(p => links.push({
        source: d,
        bundle: d.bundle,
        target: p
    }))
})

var bundles = levels.reduce(((a, x) => a.concat(x.bundles)), [])

// reverse pointer from parent to bundles
bundles.forEach(b => b.parents.forEach(p => {
    if (p.bundles_index === undefined) {
        p.bundles_index = {}
    }
    if (!(b.id in p.bundles_index)) {
        p.bundles_index[b.id] = []
    }
    p.bundles_index[b.id].push(b)
}))

nodes.forEach(n => {
    if (n.bundles_index !== undefined) {
        n.bundles = Object.keys(n.bundles_index).map(k => n.bundles_index[k])
    } else {
        n.bundles_index = {}
        n.bundles = []
    }
    n.bundles.forEach((b, i) => b.i = i)
})

links.forEach(l => {
    if (l.bundle.links === undefined) {
        l.bundle.links = []
    }
    l.bundle.links.push(l)
})

// layout
const padding = 20
const node_height = 22
const node_width = 70
const bundle_width = 14
const level_y_padding = 16
const metro_d = 4
const c = 16
const min_family_height = 16

nodes.forEach(n => n.height = (Math.max(1, n.bundles.length) - 1) * metro_d)

var x_offset = padding
var y_offset = padding
levels.forEach(l => {
    x_offset += l.bundles.length * bundle_width
    y_offset += level_y_padding
    l.forEach((n, i) => {
        n.x = n.level * node_width + x_offset
        n.y = node_height + y_offset + n.height / 2

        y_offset += node_height + n.height
    })
})

var i = 0
levels.forEach(l => {
    l.bundles.forEach(b => {
        b.x = b.parents[0].x + node_width + (l.bundles.length - 1 - b.i) * bundle_width
        b.y = i * node_height
    })
    i += l.length
})

links.forEach(l => {
    l.xt = l.target.x
    l.yt = l.target.y + l.target.bundles_index[l.bundle.id].i * metro_d - l.target.bundles.length * metro_d / 2 + metro_d / 2
    l.xb = l.bundle.x
    l.xs = l.source.x
    l.ys = l.source.y
})

// compress vertical space
var y_negative_offset = 0
levels.forEach(l => {
    y_negative_offset += -min_family_height + d3.min(l.bundles, b => d3.min(b.links, link => (link.ys - c) - (link.yt + c))) || 0
    l.forEach(n => n.y -= y_negative_offset)
})

// very ugly, I know
links.forEach(l => {
    l.yt = l.target.y + l.target.bundles_index[l.bundle.id].i * metro_d - l.target.bundles.length * metro_d / 2 + metro_d / 2
    l.ys = l.source.y
    l.c1 = l.source.level - l.target.level > 1 ? node_width + c : c
    l.c2 = c
})

const cluster = d3.cluster()
    .size([width, height]);

const root = d3.hierarchy(links);
cluster(root);
let oValues = Object.values(root)[0];
let linkks = oValues.map(x => x.bundle.links);

linkks.forEach((linkk) => {
    //nodeG1 are nodes that have children
    let nodeG1 = svg.append("g")
        .selectAll("circle")
        .data(linkk)
        .join("circle")
        .attr("cx", d => d.target.x)
        .attr("cy", d => d.target.y)
        .attr("fill", "lightblue")
        .attr("stroke", (d) => {
            return '#' + Math.floor(16777215 * Math.sin(3 * Math.PI / (5 * (parseInt(d.target.level) + 1)))).toString(16);
        })
        .attr("r", 6);
    //nodeG11 are nodes that have parents
    let nodeG11 = svg.append("g")
        .selectAll("circle")
        .data(linkk)
        .join("circle")
        .attr("cx", d => d.source.x)
        .attr("cy", d => d.source.y)
        .attr("fill", "gray")
        .attr("stroke", (d) => {
            return '#' + Math.floor(16777215 * Math.sin(3 * Math.PI / (5 * (parseInt(d.source.level) + 1)))).toString(16);
        })
        .attr("r", 6);


    let nodeG2 = svg.append("g")
        .attr("font-family", "papyrus")
        .attr("font-size", 16)
        .selectAll("text")
        .data(linkk)
        .join("text")
        .attr("class", "text")
        .attr("x", d => d.target.x + padding)
        .attr("y", d => d.target.y)
        .text(d => d.target.id )
        .attr("fill", (d) => {
            return '#' + 0;
        });

    let nodeG22 = svg.append("g")
        .attr("font-family", "papyrus")
        .attr("font-size", 16)
        .selectAll("text")
        .data(linkk)
        .join("text")
        .attr("class", "text")
        .attr("x", d => d.source.x + padding)
        .attr("y", d => d.source.y)
        .text(d => d.source.id )
        .attr("fill", (d) => {
            return '#' + 0;
        });

    let nodeG = svg.append('g')
        .attr('class', 'node')
        .selectAll("path")
        .data(linkk)
        .join('path')
        .attr("class", "link")
        .attr("d", d3.linkHorizontal()
            .source(d => [d.xs, d.ys])
            .target(d => [d.xt, d.yt]))
        .attr("fill", "none")
        .attr("stroke-opacity", 10)
        .attr("stroke-width", .75)
        .attr("stroke", (d) => {
            return '#' + Math.floor(16776960 * Math.sin(3 * Math.PI / (4 * parseInt(d.source.level)))).toString(16);
        });
});
```

```css
path {
    display: block;
    z-index: 0;
}

text,
circle {
    display: block;
    z-index: 1000;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="greek.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="main.css"/>

<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Here</title>
</head>

<body style="background-color: antiquewhite;">
<center>
    <h style="font-size:50px">Greek and Norse Gods: </h>
</center>

<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>
<script src="greek.js"></script>
<script src="norse.js"></script>

</body>





</html>
```

Is there a way to get the two visuals to appear side-by-side?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like there's only one svg element. I think you're appending both tree structures to the same svg and element and overwriting the first one with the second.  Try to create two svg elements and seperately append the greek and norse nodes. Didn't have a chance to test it, however, maybe it helps.